# Meaning of the ⊥ symbol in distributed algorithm context

Tags: algorithm, tree, distributed-computing, distributed-system, broadcasting

I am doing the research of the distributed algorithms using [this](http://www.cs.yale.edu/homes/aspnes/classes/465/notes.pdf) resource.

In the pseudo code of broadcasting/flooding algorithm there is the symbol "⊥", which I can't determine meaning of.

According to the mathematical meanings of this symbol it can mean "false" as well as "contradicts" or "independent of".

But in the context of the example [here](http://postimg.org/image/of6k08u1r/) it's not very obvious what exactly is meant, because they first compare node id with root and then if that clause isn't true, they assign this symbol to parent.

I'd appreciate any clarifications.

Comment: It's "bottom", which you can think of as "null" or "not yet defined", https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type